# Element appears exactly once in the list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, predicate

I want to write a predicate which check if the Element appeares exactly once in the List.

```
once(Element, List).
```

My code:

```
once(X, [H | T]) :-
    \+ X = H,
    once(X, T).
once(X, [X | T]) :-
    \+ member(X, T).

?- once(c, [b,a,a,c,b,a]).
true

?- once(b, [b,a,a,c,b,a]).
false.
```

But if I ask:

```
once(X, [b,a,a,c,b,a]).
```

Prolog answers:

```
false
```

Why? Prolog should find X = c solution. Where is bug?

Comment: interesting - my first attempt at writing this procedure was exactly the same and I too was wondering why I couldn't substitute the 1st arg for a logvar

Comment: i think the error comes from not fully grasping the concept of unification, i.e. using it in the wrong way here as you might use == in a procedural language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running a `trace` in prolog can be very helpful in determining the answer to this sort of question. We'll do the trace manually here for illustration.

Let's look at your predicate:

```
once(X, [H | T]) :-
    \+ X = H,
    once(X, T).
once(X, [X | T]) :-
    \+ member(X, T).
```

Let's consider now the query:

```
once(X, [b,a,a,c,b,a]).
```

First, Prolog attempts the first clause of your predicate. The head is `once(X, [H|T])` and first expression is `\+ X = H`, which will become:

```
once(X, [b|[a,a,c,b,a]]) :-  % [H|T] instantiated with [b,a,a,c,b,a] here
                             %   So, H is b, and T is [a,a,c,b,a]
    \+ X = b,
    ...
```

`X` is instantiated (be unified with) with the atom `b` here, and the result of that unification succeeds. However, you have a negation in front of this, so the result of `\+ X = b`, when `X` is initially unbound, will be false since `X = b` unifies `X` with `b` and is true.

The first clause thus fails. Prolog moves to the next clause. The clause head is `once(X, [X|T])` and following is `\+ member(X, T)`, which become:

```
once(b, [b|[a,a,c,b,a]]) :-    % X was instantiated with 'b' here,
                               %   and T instantiated with [a,a,c,b,a]
    \+ member(b, [a,a,c,b,a]).
```

`member(b, [a,a,c,b,a])` succeeds because `b` is a member of `[a,a,c,b,a]`. Therefore, `\+ member(b, [a,a,c,b,a])` fails.

The second clause fails, too.

There are no more clauses for the predicate `once(X, [b,a,a,c,b,a])`. All of them failed. So the query fails. The primary issue is that `\+ X = H` (or even `X \= H`, when `X` is not instantiated, won't choose a value from the list that is not the same as the value instantiated in `H`. Its behavior isn't logically what you want.

A more straight-on approach to the predicate would be:

```
once(X, L) :-           % X occurs once in L if...
    select(X, L, R),    % I can remove X from L giving R, and
    \+ member(X, R).    % X is not a member of R
```

The `select` will query as desired for uninstantiated `X`, so this will yield:

```
?- once(c, [b,a,a,c,b,a]).
true ;
false.

?-  once(b, [b,a,a,c,b,a]).
false.

?- once(X, [b,a,a,c,b,a]).
X = c ;
false.
```

As an aside, I'd avoid the predicate name `once` since it is the name of a built-in predicate in Prolog. But it has no bearing on this particular problem.

Comment: 'list_unique', or possibly just 'unique' would be a better predicate name?

Comment: @bph probably, since `once` is already used in some prolog implementations (such as SWI). I was just rolling with the OP's choice of names here.

Answer (score 2):

Using [prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif) we can preserve [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity)!

The following code is based on the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22748895/4609915) by @lurker, but is **logically pure**:

```
onceMember_of(X,Xs) :-
   select(X,Xs,Xs0),
   maplist(dif(X),Xs0).
```

Let's look at some queries:

```
?- onceMember_of(c,[b,a,a,c,b,a]).
true ;                              % succeeds, but leaves choicepoint
false.
?- onceMember_of(b,[b,a,a,c,b,a]).
false.
?- onceMember_of(X,[b,a,a,c,b,a]).
X = c ;
false.
```

The code is **monotone**, so we get logically sound answers for more general uses, too!

```
?- onceMember_of(X,[A,B,C]).
X = A, dif(A,C), dif(A,B) ;
X = B, dif(B,C), dif(B,A) ;
X = C, dif(C,B), dif(C,A) ;
false.
```

Let's look at all lists in increasing size:

```
?- length(Xs,_), onceMember_of(X,Xs).
Xs = [X] ;
Xs = [X,_A],        dif(X,_A) ;
Xs = [_A,X],        dif(X,_A) ;
Xs = [ X,_A,_B],    dif(X,_A), dif(X,_B) ;
Xs = [_A, X,_B],    dif(X,_A), dif(X,_B) ;
Xs = [_A,_B, X],    dif(X,_A), dif(X,_B) ;
Xs = [ X,_A,_B,_C], dif(X,_A), dif(X,_B), dif(X,_C) ...
```

At last, let's have the *most general query*:

```
?- onceMember_of(X,Xs).
Xs = [X] ;
Xs = [X,_A],       dif(X,_A) ;
Xs = [X,_A,_B],    dif(X,_A), dif(X,_B) ;
Xs = [X,_A,_B,_C], dif(X,_A), dif(X,_B),dif(X,_C) ...
```

#### Edit 2015-05-13

We can do even better by using [`selectfirst/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30207770/4609915), a drop-in replacement of `select/3`:

```
onceMember_ofB(X,Xs) :-
   selectfirst(X,Xs,Xs0),
   maplist(dif(X),Xs0).
```

Let's run `onceMember_of/2` and `onceMember_ofB/2` head to head:

```
?- onceMember_of(c,[b,a,a,c,b,a]).
true ;                              % succeeds, but leaves choicepoint
false.
?- onceMember_ofB(c,[b,a,a,c,b,a]).
true.                               % succeeds deterministically
```

But we can still get better! Consider:

```
?- onceMember_ofB(X,[A,B,C]).
X = A, dif(A,C), dif(A,B) ;
X = B, dif(B,C), dif(A,B),dif(B,A) ;             % 1 redundant constraint
X = C, dif(A,C),dif(C,A), dif(B,C),dif(C,B) ;    % 2 redundant constraints
false.
```

Note the redundant `dif/2` constraints? They come from the goal
`maplist(dif(X),Xs0)` and we can eliminate them, like so:

```
onceMember_ofC(E,[X|Xs]) :-
   if_(E = X, maplist(dif(X),Xs),
              onceMember_ofC(E,Xs)).
```

Let's see if **it works!**

```
?- onceMember_ofC(X,[A,B,C]).
X = A, dif(A,C), dif(A,B) ;
X = B, dif(B,C), dif(B,A) ;
X = C, dif(C,B), dif(C,A) ;
false.
```

Comment: They are rather mutually exclusive cases

Comment: Each answer describes a set of solution that is disjoint of the other answers' solutions.

Comment: one of my goals is to get my prolog to a level where i actually understand repeat's answers. i will have to up my game significantly..

Comment: @bph.  We share common goals;)